# How make Debian wait for all VirtualBox guests to stop during shutdown/reboot?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, shutdown

I am using the `vboxautostart-service` to start all my vms on system boot (Debian 7), they've been configured with this command:
`VBoxManage modifyvm '<vm-name>' --autostart-enabled on --autostop-type savestate`.

I can also stop them manually by executing `service vboxautostart-service stop`, this takes about 10 seconds to save state for all vms.

However, if i reboot the host machine (ctrl+alt+del or executing `reboot`) it won't wait for the vm's to save their state, and next time I boot up they all have the state `Aborted`. I tried modifying the `vboxautostart-service` by adding a `sleep 15`, but to no effect. The processes seem to get killed off, I suppose because they don't exit fast enough.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short... you need to write your own init.d script to run on run-levels 0(halt) and/or 6(reboot) and perhaps run-level 1 (single-user-mode, typical for recovery situations).

For example, in /etc/init.d/virtualbox, create something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          virtualbox_start_and_stop
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: 
# Description:       Start virtualbox on boot, and shutdown safely on shutdown/reboot.
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting Virtualbox "

    # Do whatever to start or resume your virtualbox instances.
    # Perhaps look for a txt file someplace with VMs that need to be restarted or resumed... then start 'em.
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping Virtualbox"

    # Do something to either shutdown or savestate your virtualbox instances.
    # maybe also save the instances that should be resumed into a txt file someplace for the start method above.

    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/virtualbox {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Make sure it's executable (`chmod +x /etc/init.d/virtualbox`)
and then run `update-rc.d virtualbox defaults` to create all the appropriate symlinks in the correct places to start/stop correctly.